# ASP.NET MVC user account disabled by default

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

I'm using the default ASP.NET identity user manager in MVC 5. Is there any way to allow users to register, but have them disabled by default? I'd like to have an admin manually approve and enable accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Add new property to Application user

```
 public partial class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
 {
      public Boolean IsApproved { get; set; }
 }
```

Then you can add implement  `CheckPasswordAsync` in `ApplicationUserManager` class overriding its supper method in `UserManager` like below

```
public override Task<bool> CheckPasswordAsync(ApplicationUser user, string password)
{
        if (!user.IsApproved )
        {
            return Task.FromResult<bool>(false);
        }
        return base.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password);
}
```

Only disadvantage of this approach is we get "Invalid login attempt" message even for unapproved users.

Answer (score 0):

The FX allows you the capability of allowing only registered users to login. There is a flag to check if the users have confirmed their email or not. The app can check for this and block the users from logging in until they confirm their email. In your case you can add another flag and check if the Admin has approved the user before allowing them to login.
You can refer the code for email confirmation http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity

Comment: I looked at that, but couldn't get `update-database -force` to change the `aspnet_Users` schema after I updated my model. So then I saw this http://typecastexception.com/post/2013/11/11/Extending-Identity-Accounts-and-Implementing-Role-Based-Authentication-in-ASPNET-MVC-5.aspx and figured I could just restrict what I wanted to a "verified user" role and accomplish the same thing.