# User only can register after Admin approval

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openid, email-confirmation

I am setting up a new mvc5 project in c# in which I am using Identity Framework and Open ID. which means a new user can register via a third party i.e. Google,Facebook,Microsoft.

So this part is done. Now I want to restrict users, means when a user will be trying to register an approval will be sent to the Admin. If the Admin accepts only then the user can register. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC user account disabled by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684385/asp-net-mvc-user-account-disabled-by-default)

Answer (score 2):

Check out a combination of Authorization Policies/ Role Based Security.  When any user registers via a third party, the code which handles the registration does all the relevant record keeping for the new user, and gives them a role of, say, "Unapproved User".  You can create as set of Controllers/ Views etc which that user can view (perhaps a profile page,  landing page with generic information, or maybe just a disclaimer page which tells them they need to wait to be approved).

From there when the Admin approves the user, the code which handles the approval changes the role to "Approved User".  This then allows them to access the full site.

I can't tell if you are using classic Asp.Net with mvc 5 or Asp.Net core but the concepts are similar (except for the auth policy stuff) in both.

Essentially you decorate the controllers/ actions you want protected with:

```c#
[Authorize("ApprovedUser")]
public class MyProtectedController
{
}

[Authorize("UnapprovedUser")]
public class MyUnprotectedController
{
}
```

For more info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.2